# Prerender not working on https with Nginx

Tags: nginx, prerender

I am having trouble including prerender in my application running on Nginx, I have defined a simple rule for rewriting all http requests to https , however prerender has some trouble with https running on a GoDaddy certificate , it caches the page but the content is blank.
I have tested it on http and it works fine , what I'm trying now is that if my `http_user_agent` is Prerender I want to keep the http url intact and otherwise rewrite the url to https.

Any help/comments/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue with prerender handling https redirects.
In our case the quick solution was to force https protocol in prerender-node configuration (I assume such option should exist for any other middleware).

```
var prerender = require('prerender-node');
prerender.protocol = 'https';
```

But after all it seems to be caused by nginx misconfiguration, which does not pass **x-forwarded-proto** header, because otherwise it should be automatically handled by the middleware https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node/blob/master/index.js#L235-L237

Answer (score 0):

You could do a simple rewrite rule for everyone except Prerender.

```
set $prerender 0;
if ($http_user_agent ~* "prerender") {
  set $prerender 1;
}
if ($prerender = 0) {
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I managed to get around this by adding a rule , but prerender somehow doesn't cache the page, I have verified my nginx config,and it works on http only as long as the request is coming via service.prerender.io , any clues as to why this could be happening